# How to report intrisically spammy user accounts?

Tags: support, flagging, users, spam, user-names

Sometimes, I notice that some very odd username is listed on Home as having earned the "Autobiographer" badge, where by "odd" I mean something very much non-mathematical and intrinsically spammy, such as [this account](https://mathoverflow.net/users/164339/el-paso-roofing). Invariably, the "About me" section turns out to be spam, actually. Is there any way to report such accounts? I can't see a "flag this user" button on the user page.

Comment: If there are any posts of that user still up, use a custom moderator flag. If there are no posts, nobody will be looking at the profile anyway. If it's a network-wide spammer, unofficial policy is to notify JNat in [The Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) and roughly a day later the account ceases to be. I do not know the perfect answer to your question, but these are the options I'm aware of.

Comment: That particular spam account has been destroyed.

Comment: Related older posts: [Flagging spam user](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3487). Related post on [math.meta.se]: [How to flag names?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15197) And on [meta.se]: [How should I flag a user account if it has no posts to flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128618) and [How do I flag a user with no posts left?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178221)

Comment: There's indeed a real flood of spam accounts: [Autobiographer](https://mathoverflow.net/help/badges/9/autobiographer)

Comment: @YCor here's a more precise list: https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/edit/1288838 limiting to those with more than 5 links in their profile, and have shown no activity for a certain period of time.

Comment: Here is a direct link to the query from David Robert's comment: https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1288838 (The link posted above will send you to *editing* the query.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flagging spam user](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3487/flagging-spam-user)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried destroying a few accounts with spammy profiles, and it takes less than 30 seconds to do each one.  However, looking through the list of "autobiographer" badge recipients, I would guess we have over 5000 such accounts, and I'm not particularly inclined to repeat this process 5000 times.

Based on [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297993/what-is-the-policy-on-destroying-users-with-very-spammy-profiles-but-have-not-po?noredirect=1&lq=1) at Meta.SE, it seems the official policy is to do nothing until they post actual spam beyond their profiles.

Comment: The suggestion which was mentioned in the previous discussion: [Spam Profiles are getting my goat. Could we have better tools for mods to deal with profile spam?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303746#303751) That seems like a reasonable things to me - why should moderators have to do manually some stuff which can be automated. Of course, it's up to Stack Exchange to actually implement this.

Comment: What about allowing to write in your profile only when you have at least 150 or 200 points?

Comment: @Mare That sounds like a good idea. It seems most unsatisfactory that spammers are effectively getting free advertising through having their names appear among the recent badges.