# How can this question have more downvotes than views?

Tags: support, votes, views

An off-topic question recently appeared on the main site. It was heavily downvoted and got deleted after only a few minutes. But at one point before the question was deleted, I noticed it had been viewed just 3 times but had received 5 downvotes (screenshot below). I saw this view count in the feed, and also when I opened the question. How does something like this happen? Is it possible to downvote a question without increasing its view count?

I included the [bug] tag in case this is a glitch. But maybe there is a simple explanation for this behavior, in which case I am curious to know what it is.

[image]

Comment: [meta.se]: [Views indicator inaccurate, shows one views on question with two close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/46974) and other [questions linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/46974).

Comment: It would be nice if this question on meta had more upvotes than views. (It would make it a bit self-referential.) Sadly, it seems that this is unlikely to happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using spam flags, a single user (with a single page view) can incure two downvotes to the post: one regular, and one automatic downvote from a spam flag.

Comment: I will add that it is recommended *against* doing both - spam-flag and downvote - at least in some cases. (Although on a healthy site spam posts should be removed rather fast anyway, so this shouldn't matter that much.)  [meta.se]: [Why shouldn't I downvote spam that I've already flagged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193916) The same thing is mentioned also on this meta: [What should I do when I see a spam post on MO?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4259)

Answer (score 4):

Given the time you posted this, it's most likely [this spam question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376075) (only visible with 10k reputation); there's a copy [over here](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/274149) in the records of a community project fighting spam across the network. That post has been [automatically flagged](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/274149/flag_logs) with four accounts, and those flags carry [an implicit downvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/295232). IIRC, casting those flags (via the API) doesn't increase the view count of a question (though the system casting the flags did fetch the question details via the API, which counts as a view) but they do decrease the score. So that's a -4 to the score, and only a +1 to the views.

More details here: [Can a machine be taught to flag spam automatically?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291301/295232)