# Should tags be removed from spam?

Tags: discussion, tags, spam

When flagging spam, I usually delete tags and replace them by `tag-removed` as well.  I just received a comment suggesting that this is not useful.  It probably doesn't matter much either way, as spam usually disappears quite quickly.  Does anyone else have an opinion?

Comment: It is better to not edit spam posts at all, and just flag them as spam (see [Should spam posts be edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110030) on Meta SE).

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up here. I was the original commenter. I don't have much of a presence on this particular site; I basically only flag spam.

Comment: Re: *spam usually disappears quite quickly.* That all depends on your definition of "quickly". As [mentioned in the MO chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9369/2022/12/16), median seems to be around 25 minutes on main and 50 minutes on meta.

Comment: That surprises me, I think the average that I have observed is much less.

Answer (score 15):

No. Spam should be flagged as spam and removed. Please limit your interactions with spam posts to exactly that.

Answer (score 3):

This would be probably more suitable as a comment, but it is too long - to have some stats on this, I'll include some [SEDE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/data-explorer/info) queries. (So that one can estimate how often tags such as [tag-removed](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/tag-removed) and [spam](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/spam) are used for spam posts.)

The table Votes [includes spam as `VoteTypeId = 12`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede), so at least some data can be obtained from this database. (I do not claim that the data there are perfectly reliable - some spam posts might have been deleted without being flagged; somebody might have flagged a post which actually isn't spam. But such exceptions will probably be rare.)

- Among the spam posts, SEDE returns [111 questions tagged tag-removed](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1669127/spam-questions-in-the-given-tag?tagname=tag-removed) and [7 questions tagged spam](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1669127/spam-questions-in-the-given-tag?tagname=spam). (The tag [spam](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/spam) was created a few times in the past - naturally, after the question was deleted the tag was gone.)
- Here are numbers of spam posts for [all tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1687757/number-of-spam-questions-per-tag-including-the-tags-which-no-longer-exist) and [only non-existent tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1687758/number-of-spam-questions-per-tag-only-the-tags-which-no-longer-exist).
- Looking at the [recent posts flagged as spam](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1687782/recent-spam-posts), the tag [tag-removed](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/tag-removed) appears repeatedly - but not too often.

Both tags were briefly mentioned in chat (in connection with spam) - [the tag spam](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9369/conversation/creating-the-tag-spam) and [the tag tag-removed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9369/conversation/using-tag-removed-for-spam).

Some related posts elsewhere:

- [Tagging spam / offensive questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57371) (on Meta Stack Exchange)
- [Should spam be tagged as [spam]?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363716) (Meta Stack Exchange)
- The tag [spam](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/spam) was mentioned on the old [tea](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/tea/info) in the thread "Tag merge/rename requests" ([page 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20130901173407/http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/34/2/tag-mergerename-requests/) and [page 3](https://web.archive.org/web/20131029093715/http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/34/3/tag-mergerename-requests/)) - but that was in a completely different context.

As usually, I will include a link to this post: [What should I do when I see a spam post on MO?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4259) (Although editing tags isn't mentioned there explicitly - only editing in general.)